# how often the user change his device, query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know "On average, how often the user change his devices by month?"

This is the `table_1` in SQL, AWS Athenas

```
id          date    month   device      carrier
-----------------------------------------------
12-ac8147   2019       4    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       5    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       5    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    Sgx1         alca
12-ac8147   2019       6    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2019       9    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2019       9    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2020       1    iPhone8,1    telc
12-ac8147   2020       10   iPhone11,2   telc
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   telc
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2020       12   iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       1    iPhone11,2   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       12   iPhone11,5   service_m
12-ac8147   2021       12   iPhone11,5   movil_tel
```

So my idea was (in SQL athenas AWS amazon)

```
with table as
(
    id, device, max(year * 100 + month) mas_n, min(year * 100 + month) min_n)
    from table_1
    where device is not null and device <> ''
    group by id, device
)
SELECT id, AVG(max_n - min_n) prom_dif
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

But this doesn't work, because it counts all the months:

```
    id              prom_dif
12-ac8147            206
```

Comment: Try `year * 12 + month` also you need to convert to `decimal` otherwise your average will be rounded

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, 
       count(distinct device) * 1.0 / count(distinct year * 100 + month) as prom_dif
from table_1
where device is not null and device <> ''
group by id
```

Comment: This works fine as long as a user doesn't change back and forth. It should be number of devices divided by number of months though. You have it vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ídea:

- For each row look at the previous row and compare the devices (using `LAG`).
- Use adjacent month numbers to easily deal with the months (`year * 12 + month`) - that is that you can easily calculate the number of months thus.
- Calculate the number of months and the number of changes for each ID.
- Divide the number of changes by the number of months.

The query:

```
select
  id,
  max(month_num) - min(month_num) + 1 as months,
  sum(change_mark) as changes,
  sum(change_mark) * 1.0 / (max(month_num) - min(month_num) + 1) as average
from
(
  select 
    id,
    year * 12 + month as month_num,
    case when device <> lag(device) over (partition by id order by year, month)
      then 1 else 0 end as change_mark
  from table_1
) changes_marked
group by id
order by id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=36112bfa58a2f1afd042a1a4d5564e2d

This takes into consideration that a user can switch from device A to B, then back to A, then back to B for instance, so we must count three changes, although it's only two different devices.

If months are missing from the table, this is considered in the calculation, too. This means, if you only have January and December and one change, then the query will show  you 0.083 (one change in twelve months).

(ID is a bad name here, by the way, because despite its name it does not uniquely identify a row in the table, but a user it seems. So better call this `user_num`, or - if a user table exists - `user_id`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think there is a mistake, since the final result is the same for everything, avg_change is 1.0 for all user

Comment: Yes, my query had several flaws. I am sorry about this. I've updated my answer with a working query.